# Private page protected with username and password

Tags: login, password, user-roles, private, username

We are building a WordPress site where one of the pages needs to be accessed via username and password.

I know that I can create a "Private" page, where the user can enter a password to view. However, our client has asked us for the ability to create unique username/password combinations for this particular page. Because of this, I'd also like to build in the ability to reset a forgotten password.

I've researched online but haven't found any viable solutions. I'm wondering if there's a best practice in place for this. I'm thinking that perhaps we create a new user role and hide the WordPress dashboard for this type of user? Am I on the right track? Any experiences would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: when you say "password" do you mean the *users* password or the *pages* password?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification -- I meant the user's password.

Comment: So really, the only prerequisite is the user **has to be logged in** to view the private page?

Comment: Correct. Logged in to view the page, but we don't want to give them access to the wordpress dashboard. Upon login, they'll go directly to the private page, instead of the dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what we're trying to do:

**IF** A user logs in and is of a specific role ( Subscriber ) then redirect them to a specific page.

**IF** A user tries to reach the admin panel, redirect them to a specific page.

We're going to use 3 hooks for the above problems:

- [login_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) - Redirect user once they login
- [after_setup_theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) - Remove admin bar
- [admin_init](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) - Keeps subscribers out of admin panel

First, let's create our redirect:

```
/**
 * Redirect subscribers to specific page
 * @param string $redirect
 * @param string $request
 * return string
 */
function member_redirect( $redirect, $request ) {
    if( current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) ) {
        return $specific_page
    }

    return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'member_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

If the current user is a subscriber, we would replace the `$specific_page` with the page URL, otherwise let them go to where they were originally headed.

Next, let's make sure subscribers can't get to the admin panel:

```
/**
 * If user is subscriber AND trying to access admin panel, redirect them to specific page
 */
function subs_adminpanel_redirect(){
    if ( current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) ){
        wp_redirect( $specific_page );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'subs_adminpanel_redirect' );
```

Again, you could replace `$specific_page` with your actual URL.

Finally, let's remove the admin bar so the user doesn't even know there's a dashboard.

```
/**
 * Remove adminbar for Subscribers
 */
function subs_remove_adminbar() { 
    if( ! current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );   
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'subs_remove_adminbar' );
```

This is pretty straight forward, if they're a subscriber remove the admin bar for them.

A step shackleton pointed out in the comments below is by default, subscribers **do not** have access to view private pages. We need to add this as a capability:

```
/**
 * Allow Subscribers to view Private Pages
 */
function add_theme_caps() {
    $role = get_role( 'subscriber' );
    $role->add_cap( 'read_private_pages' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps' );
```

---

You would throw all this into your `functions.php` file at some place and test it out. Again, this only works for subscribers and only if you replace `$specific_page` with your actual page URL.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks so much for the thoughtful reply. I ran into 2 issues, which you may want to edit above 1) in the 2nd and 3rd functions above, remove the ! before current_user_can, and 2) subscribers cannot view private pages, so I added (comments wont allow line breaks, so posting to next comment):

Comment: `/**
 * Allow Subscribers to View Private Pages
 */
function add_theme_caps() {
    $role = get_role( 'subscriber' );
    $role->add_cap( 'read_private_pages' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');`